# Use Comparison test to check whether the series converges or not.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series  $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{2+5n}{(2+n)^{4}}$ . **Use Comparison test to check whether the series converges or not.** $$ $$ my approach - $ \frac{2+5n}{(2+n)^{4}}  < \frac{5(n+1)}{(n+2)^{4}} < \frac{5(n+1)}{5(n+1)^{3}} =\frac{1}{(n+1)^{2}} <\frac{1}{n^{2}}=b_{n} , say $ .  **My question is this $ b_{n} $ is right ? Any help is there .**

Comment: you can take a shortcut: $\frac{2+5n}{(2+n)^4}<\frac{5(n+2)}{(n+2)^4}<\frac{5}{(n+2)^3}<5\cdot \frac{1}{n^3}<\infty$

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, your answer is correct. However, you multiplied the denominator by $5$ in the third term of your inequality. If done correctly, you should end with the comparing series as $\displaystyle \frac{5}{n^2}$, which converges, because it is a scalar multiple of the convergent series $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: using $ b_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{2}} $ , we have $ lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=0 $ , so how can i decide whether the series diverges or converges ?  I think a new approach is required . any help

Comment: think about it this way. using the convergent series. if you can place the sum of $a_n$ between $b_n$ and 0, and $b_n$ has a finite value, then $a_n$ will have a finite value too, because it is squeezed in between

Comment: yes i got $ b_{n}=\frac{1}{n^{3}} $. It is working

Comment: yup. both 1/n^3 and 1/n^2 work.